# Bootstrap 4 Pills Nav with Dropdown Menus - Capture click

Tags: bootstrap-4, nav-pills

I am able to create a Bootstrap4 Pills Nav, no problem.  What I'm trying to do is capture the click of the dropdown menu item that is clicked

MediaCalls
      
      
        Open
        OverDue
        Complete
        OnHold

I've tried at least 3 different functions to capture the href of the menu item clicked.  Only one reacts to click but it reacts on the menu click and not on the menu-item

```
    $('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
      // $(".dropdown a").on("show.bs.dropdown", function (event) {
      var x = $(this).text();
      alert(x);
    });

    $('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]').on("show.bs.dropdown", function(e) {
      Alert("1");
    });

    $(".dropdown").on("show.bs.dropdown", function(e) {
      var linkText = $(e.relatedTarget).text(); // Get the link text
      alert("2");
    });
```

Any help to capthure the href of the menu ITEM clicked is appreciated.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/timcadieux/71Lp5ba8/13/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to capture the **href**  property of the clicked menu item you can, on dom ready, attach a click event handler to:

```
a.dropdown-item
```

```js
$('a.dropdown-item').on('click', function(event) {
    var x = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(x);
});
```

```css
.row {
    background: #f8f9fa;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
    border: solid 1px #6c757d;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">


<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills dropdown-menu-left">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                MediaCalls
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="MediaCalls">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#mediacallsOpen">Open</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#mediacallsOverDue">OverDue</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#mediacallsComplete">Complete</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#mediacallsOnHold">OnHold</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```